# Changing click event delay based on dynamically added class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code that adds a class to the body if the user touches the screen:

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function onFirstTouch() {
// we could use a class
document.body.classList.add('user-is-touching');


// we only need to know once that a human touched the screen, so we can stop 
listening now
window.removeEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch, false);
}, false);
```

If want to perform an if statement in jQuery such that if the class `user-is-touching` is in the body, the click of a link should scroll down to the div after five seconds. If the class `user-is-touching` is not present it should scroll down immediately once the link is clicked.

Below is the code:

```js
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function onFirstTouch() {
  // we could use a class
  document.body.classList.add('user-is-touching');


  // we only need to know once that a human touched the screen, so we can stop listening now
  window.removeEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch, false);
}, false);

if ($('body').hasClass('user-is-touching')) {

  $(".o-c").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".one").offset().top
      }, 2000);
    }, 5000);
  });
} else {
  $(".o-c").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".one").offset().top
      }, 2000);
    }, 000);
  });
}
```

```css
.left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="left">

    <ul class="pivot-nav">
      <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a class="o-c default-underline custom-scroll-link" href="#one" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">1</a></li>

    </ul>

  </div>



  <div class="one">
    Some more TEXT HERE
  </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the check for the body class to be there when the link is clicked within the event handler itself not when you are attaching the touch event handler

```
  $(".o-c").click(function() {
    var animateDelay = 2000, timeoutDelay = 0;
    if ($('body').hasClass('user-is-touching')) {
      animateDelay = 2000;
      timeoutDelay = 5000;
    } 
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".one").offset().top
      }, animateDelay);
    }, timeoutDelay);
  });
```